# ATmega168 TQFP vs. 28DIP - different behavior after programming

Tags: atmega, atmel, tqfp

I have developed a program for ATmega168 using Atmel Studio 7.0 and Atmel-ICE as debugging interface.

The development was done on a 28DIP package, since it's easy to work with it on a breadboard. Moving from the prototype to PCB, I chose a 32pin TQFP package instead of 28DIP (please see the part numbers below).

I can program the PCB device with Atmel-ICE without any warning or issues after reading its signature. The device gets flashed, however it does not do anything afterward as if the program isn't there. I wonder if anyone else has seen this?

ATMEGA168-20AU-ND, TQFP 32pin package.
ATMEGA168-20PU-ND, 28DIP package

---

The default TQFP package had HIGH.WDTON (Hardware Fuse Watchdog always on) and that was not the case for my prototype where I did compare and match in Timer1 to write an interrupt driven delay function.  Turning watchdog on was messing up my delay function, and when I turned it off, the 32 pin package also did what I expected. Thank you all for your responses.

Hamid

Comment: I'd start by verifying that my PCB is correct.  The two parts you have listed are identical apart from the packaging.  The TQFP has extra Vcc and GND pins.  Be sure they are connected properly.

Comment: Please add schematic and/or layout for better answers.

Comment: Did you set the fuses to the correct values? Especially the fuses for the clock source?

Comment: What is the supply voltage and is it same on both boards? What is the clock speed and is it same on both boards? Fuse bits same? Schematic same (except package difference)?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and remove it from the question (by editing). Yes, you can and you should self-answer the questions if you figure things out yourself!